# Cannot install GTK 3 for Windows

Tags: c, gtk, lib

I'm trying to install GTK, but nothing i find works. I'm using the MSYS2 install, but it always say :Target not found". I found a direct dump having the BIN and everything, but i don't know what to do with it, and the GTK website seems to have nothing that helps me.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post

Comment: It could happened that you missed something. [Here is a working tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVopEfWiFX88_zUzk08ZdrIc).

Comment: @Michi i watched your video, and it always just said "Target not found: pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3: